# error after upgarade "react-native" "^0.70.1",

Tags: react-native

after updating react native 0.64.3  npx react-native run-android app installing with icon but suddenly got this error and a white blank screen

: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors

.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/40340d0266c697f483e4d8d82154afae/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6e559baadda92a2bf6e59daa069e5722/jetified-react-native-0.70.1-debug-api.jar!/META-INF/ReactAndroid_debug.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bbe64d757289d178f000992f4ab3090b/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with metadata for android.

Follow the upgrade helper from react-native wiki.

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.64.3&to=0.70.1